# Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I can not figure out What's wrong here.!! i have many table 
`print, lamn, sec_lam, thi_lam, rewind, slit, ink` and all of these table related by job_code column, i am trying to add foreign key each of these table from order_basic, but mysql give me `Cannot add foreign key constraint` error.
and also please suggest me which column should index on each table. here is my table structure..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dispatch` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `job_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dispatch_qty` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `no_bags` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `no_pan` int(11)  NOT NULL,
  `no_roll` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ch_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks` text NOT NULL,
  `prepaired` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`job_code`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`job_code`) REFERENCES order_basic(`job_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Here is other table that i like to foreign key form this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_basic` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cd_date` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `po_num` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `po_date` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `del_date` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `job_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `print_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `remarks` text,
  `prepaired` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,'job_code')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Have you tried searching for the error message on SO? There are many questions about foreign key errors, I'll bet anything you can find one that's like your problem.

Comment: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint 
yes there are  many answer about this error. but i cannot figure it out what exactly issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a composite primary key on `order_basic`:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,'job_code')`
```

but your foreign key only references `job_code`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (`job_code`) REFERENCES order_basic(`job_code`)
```

Since `job_code` is not constrained to be unique in `order_basic` you cannot reference it in a foreign key because the same code could reference more than one record in `order_basic`.

e.g. In order_basic you could feasibly have:

```
id | job_code
---+---------
 1 |     1
 2 |     1
 3 |     1
 4 |     1
```

If you have a job_code of 1 in `dispatch`, which record is this supposed to reference?

If `job_code` is unique in `order_basic` then you can either just make this your primary key, or add a unique constraint on this column which will allow you to reference it with a foreign key. 
If it is not unique then you should not store `job_code` in dispatch, and instead store the corresponding `id` from `order_basic` and make this your foreign key. If you need to get the `job_code` for a specific dispatch record you can just join using the `order_basic.id` column.

Comment: i got exectly now thanks for super description. please tell me about indexing in database.

Comment: There are entire books written on indexing in databases, and entire websites ([Use the Index Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) as an example), so I can't really answer a question that broad in a comment, or an answer for that matter. If you have a specific question about indexing then you should probably ask a new question. Thanks.